# UTF-16 perl input output

Tags: windows, perl, io, cygwin, utf-16

I am writing a script that takes a UTF-16 encoded text file as input and outputs a UTF-16 encoded text file.

```
use open "encoding(UTF-16)";

open INPUT, "< input.txt"
   or die "cannot open > input.txt: $!\n";
open(OUTPUT,"> output.txt");

while(<INPUT>) {
   print OUTPUT "$_\n"
}
```

Let's just say that my program writes everything from input.txt into output.txt.

This WORKS perfectly fine in my cygwin environment, which is using "This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for cygwin-thread-multi-64int"

But in my Windows environment, which is using "This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread",

Every line in output.txt is pre-pended with crazy symbols except the first line.

For example:

```
<FIRST LINE OF TEXT>
਀　　　　㈀  ㄀Ⰰ ㈀Ⰰ 嘀愀 ㌀ 䌀栀椀愀 䐀⸀⸀⸀  儀甀愀渀最 䠀ഊ<SECOND LINE OF TEXT>
...
```

Can anyone give some insight on why it works on cygwin but not windows?

EDIT: After printing the encoded layers as suggested.

In Windows environment:

```
unix
crlf
encoding(UTF-16)
utf8
unix
crlf
encoding(UTF-16)
utf8
```

In Cygwin environment:

```
unix
perlio
encoding(UTF-16)
utf8
unix
perlio
encoding(UTF-16)
utf8
```

The only difference is between the perlio and crlf layer.

Comment: Perhaps those "crazy symbols" are windows not displaying UTF16 in whatever you're using to view them ;)

Comment: I am using Notepad++ to display output.txt. It works fine if I use cygwin to run the script and generate the file, but it is also full of crazy symbols when I use windows to run the script

Comment: Try upgrading your Windows Perl to 5.14 or 5.16, that will eliminate the possibility this is a 5.12 bug.  Either [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ I was going to wait and give a thorough answer, but it's probably better if I give you a quick answer than nothing. ]

The problem is that `crlf` and the `encoding` layers are in the wrong order. Not your fault.

For example, say you do `print "a\nb\nc\n";` using UTF-16le (since it's simpler and it's probably what you actually want). You'd end up with

```
61 00 0D 0A 00 62 00 0D 0A 00 63 00 0D 0A 00
```

instead of

```
61 00 0D 00 0A 00 62 00 0D 00 0A 00 63 00 0D 00 0A 00
```

I don't think you can get the right results with the `open` pragma or with `binmode`, but it can be done using `open`.

```
open(my $fh, '<:raw:encoding(UTF-16):crlf', $qfn)
```

You'll need to append a `:utf8` with some older version, IIRC.

It works on cygwin because the `crlf` layer is only added on Windows. There you'd get

```
61 00 0A 00 62 00 0A 00 63 00 0A 00
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the purpose of these different encoding layers work. But this solved my problem: open my $output,">:raw:encoding(UTF-16)", "output.txt"; Appending :crlf did not seem to make a difference (which is surprising since you said the problem arises from the wrong order). But prepending :raw is necessary (same problem occurs otherwise)

Comment: The difference with and without :crlf is the line endings used (CR LF vs LF)

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your encoding.  It should be `use open ":encoding(UTF-16)"`  Note the colon.  I don't know why it would work on Cygwin but not Windows, but could also be a 5.12 vs 5.14 thing.  Perl seems to make up for it, but it could be what's causing your problem.

If that doesn't do it, check if the encoding is being applied to your filehandles.

```
print map { "$_\n" } PerlIO::get_layers(*INPUT);
print map { "$_\n" } PerlIO::get_layers(*OUTPUT);
```

Use lexical filehandles (ie. `open my $fh, "<", $file`).  Glob filehandles are *global* and thus something else in your program might be interfering with them.

If all that checks out, if lexical filehandles are getting the `encoding(UTF-16)` applied, let us know and we can try something else.

UPDATE:  [This may provide your answer](http://www.haboogo.com/matching_patterns/2009/01/utf-16-processing-issue-in-perl.html): "*[BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)ed UTF files are not suitable for streaming models, and they must be slurped as binary files instead.*"  Looks like you have to read the file in as binary and do the encoding as a string.  This may have been a bug fixed in 5.14.

UPDATE 2:  Yep, I can confirm this is [a bug that was fixed in 5.14](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/commit/6d51015587940c2032a6533d886163f69ca028f9).

Comment: As you suggested, I added the colon and changed to use lexical file handles but it had no effect. Please see the edit to my question for the print outputs. The only difference was that there was a crlf layer in Windows environment, and a perlio layer in cygwin envrionment.

Comment: @aylz5073 See update. You may have bumped into a UTF-16 encoding bug in 5.12.

Comment: I just tried it with ActivePerl 5.16 and it did not eliminate the problem. One other observation I want to make is that if I change the encoding from ":encoding(UTF-16)" to ":encoding(UTF-16LE)", then output.txt becomes some form of binary file full of NUL markers instead of just pre-pending some weird symbols to my lines of text as shown in my original post. I guess I will try the solution in the link you provided and keep you updated.

Comment: @aylz5073 The only thing I can think at this point is to give Strawberry Perl a shot.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the BOM. Use UTF-16le and you'll get the same prob. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for both your help. I really appreciate it.